# Need a helping hand organizing an array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, object, jtable

I am making JTables in Java, and have accounted an annoying problem.

```
    public Object[][] noName(String[] col) {
     final Object[][] obj = new Object[col.length][];       
     for (int i = 0; i < col.length; i++) obj[i] = createColumnList(col[i]);
     return obj;
    }
```

I am creating an Object[][] to match the JTable, but with this way the sorting is coming out all wrong...

This is how this ends:

```
COL1     COL1
COL2     COL2
```

This is how I want it to be:

```
COL1     COL2
COL1     COL2
```

Where COL1 and COL2 is an array, which comes from `createColumnList(col[i])`
What do I do?

Comment: Show `createColumnList(col[i]);`. Also explain this `but with this way the sorting is coming out all wrong`. And explain `This is how this ends:` and `This is how I want it to be:`. Basically explain everything beacuse it makes no sense.

Comment: This solved the problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20165869/need-help-creating-an-array