# Need help creating an array

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, jtable

I need some help getting started.
I have one array storing several arrays (in this case, lets say 3, this may be a lot more or less):

```
mainarray {arr, arr, arr}
```

All the arrays within the mainarray have the same amount of values, but this may also change to fewer or less
Lets say I have following arrays:

```
mainarray {
  arr{"1","2","3"};
  arr{"One","Two","Three"};
  arr{"Red","Blue","Yellow"};
}
```

Everytime I try to make this Object[][] the sorting comes out like this:

```
Object {{"1","2","3"}, {"One","Two","Three"}, {"Red","Blue","Yellow"}};
```

Here comes my problem:
Is there a way of making this arrays into an Object[][], but with this sorting?

```
Object {{"1","One","Red"}, {"2","Two","Blue"}, {"3","Three","Yellow"}};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can translate the arrangement of the arrays using a couple of loops.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
    Object arr1[] = { "1", "2", "3" };
    Object arr2[] = { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    Object arr3[] = { "Red", "Blue", "Yellow" };
    //make an array of arrays
    Object allArr[] = { arr1, arr2, arr3 };
    //the new array to store values
    Object arr4[][] = new Object[3][3];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < 3 && k < 3; j++, k++) {
            //take the first array from array of arrays
            Object tmp[] = (Object[]) allArr[k];
            //take the ith element of each individual array and store in the new array in correct position 
            arr4[i][j] = tmp[i];

        }
    }
     //print the new array
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            System.out.print(arr4[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

This works for your example. You can generalise it further.

output

```
1 One Red 
2 Two Blue 
3 Three Yellow
```

Comment: change `< 3` to `< allArr.length` and change `new Object[3][3]` to `new Object [arr1.length][allArr.length]`. Make it work for all sizes of arrays.

Comment: @mikeyaworski let OP do that :-) Thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 2):

#### Code

This code works for arrays of all sizes, assuming that they are of equal sizes though (as you said).
This is just a modified version of [n1234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2308497/n1234)'s code.

```
Object arr1[] = { "1", "2", "3"};
Object arr2[] = { "One", "Two", "Three"};
Object arr3[] = { "Red", "Blue", "Yellow"};

Object allArr[] = { arr1, arr2, arr3 }; // combination of the arrays

Object arr4[][] = new Object[arr1.length][allArr.length]; // array to be rearranged

// define the new, rearranged array
for (int i = 0; i < arr4.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0, k = 0; j < arr4[i].length && k < arr4[i].length; j++, k++) 
    {
        Object tmp[] = (Object[]) allArr[k];
        arr4[i][j] = tmp[i];
    }
}       

// print the array
for (Object r[] : arr4) {
    for (Object c : r)
        System.out.print(c + " ");
    System.out.println("");
}
```

---

#### Input/Output

Input:

```
Object arr1[] = { "1", "2", "3", "4"};
Object arr2[] = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four"};
Object arr3[] = { "Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green"};
```

Output:

> 1 One Red
>  
>   2 Two Blue 
>   3 Three Yellow

Input:

```
Object arr1[] = { "1", "2", "3"};
Object arr2[] = { "One", "Two", "Three"};
Object arr3[] = { "Red", "Blue", "Yellow"};
```

Output:

> 1 One Red
>  
>   2 Two Blue 
>   3 Three Yellow 
>   4 Four Green

Comment: you could have left some work for OP :-). It is basically same code as mine :-)

Comment: @n1234 I also showed him how to use the other version of the for loop, which is much cleaner for printing. And I think I should give him all of what he asked for, considering he said the array sizes could be different. But yes, it's just a modified version of yours. I should give you credit.

Comment: Thanks for answers! Both were right, but I gave credit to @n1234, because he was the first one out :)